# Kotlin Naming Conventions

Tags: kotlin, naming-conventions

Am a bit of an aesthetic programmer and I ventured into Kotlin lately. I named my static variable as `val PREF_NAME = "onb"` and got an alert in android studio
[image]

I looked into this but it's contradicting in the official Kotlin documentation

> Names of constants (properties marked with const, or top-level or object val properties with no custom get function that hold deeply immutable data) should use uppercase underscore-separated names:
>
> `const val MAX_COUNT = 8`
>
> `val USER_NAME_FIELD = "UserName"`

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Fields declared in classes aren't static. Therefore, they don't follow the naming conventions for static variables

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think what you're doing is placing your `val` inside a regular class, like this:

```
class X {
    val PREF_NAME = "onb"
}
```

By doing this, you're giving a separate property to every instance of the class - even though they'll all have the same value, this isn't quite the same as having a single static constant in Java terms.

---

The places where constants are expected to be placed for them to only have a single instance are laid out in the documentation you've quoted, specifically this part:

> properties marked with const, or top-level or object val properties with no custom get function

So these properties can be top level (not nested in anything else within the file):

```
val PREF_NAME = "onb"
```

Or inside an `object`:

```
object X {
    val PREF_NAME = "onb"
}
```

Or inside a companion object:

```
class X {
    companion object {
        val PREF_NAME = "onb"
    }
}
```

These are also the places where you may mark a property with the [`const`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#compile-time-constants) modifier, if it's constant at compile time.

Answer (score 8):

I am guessing that your property is in a class, in which case it neither top-level nor an object value:

```
class A {
    val justAProperty = ""
}

val TOP_LEVEL_VAL_PROPERTY = ""

object B {
    val OBJECT_VAL_PROPERTY = ""
}
```

Frankly, the difference between those is minimal. I always use camel case for all properties but for the `const val`, for which I use upper case to mark their different nature.